# What are the ways available for getting Database from SQL and display it in web page?

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

1. I know JSP,PHP and ASP.Net are there apart from these what are the
   ways are there to get data from database.
2. It is possible by using J query,Bootstrap and Angular JS. If any
   other way means suggest.

Comment: Bootstrap does not provide any such functionality, jQuery and Angular both have ways to pass data back and forth between a server and client but both any method you use will require server side code to actually deal with the SQL.  But honestly, this question is not suited to SO as it is far too broad. Luckily, information on this topic is quite easy to google for ;)

Comment: Now i am using PHP which one is good to use.

Comment: For me, PHP is Okay.

Comment: It depends on so many factors it's hard to say. jQuery's `.ajax()` is likely the easiest solution to learn and implemen. Angular can help alot with your UI and displaying all the info easily with very little code but IMHO the takes a good deal more to learn

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Server Side** scripting languages are diff from **Client Side**.
jQuery , Angular and Bootstrap, though they are not scripting languages, they are frontend frameworks/libraries that doesnt have access to your server. However, you can use jQuery and Angular to make Ajax requests to the server to fetch database results.

You can check here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting#Languages

To conclude, this question is to broad to answer. It still depends on what type of database you are using.

Comment: Now i am using MY SQL.

Comment: The key point here is `this question is to broad to answer.`

Comment: PHP and MySQL is a good enough team for me. So you can stick with it.

Comment: @Selvam:: since u r curious to know that posibility, there is a trade off for this is node.js/mongodB/cassandra...here u r doing ur code in javascript only for achieiving db calls and everything what a server side language does...may be this idea maybe helpful for u. But again node.js is a server side language only eventhough we r using javascript for that...

Comment: just google for node.js to know more about that offers you in your project...all the best